# Notify user if file is used by other user in windows

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows

I am working in a project where all developers are working in a single windows system through **remote sessions**(remote desktop).Where we all have to share a **common workspace** folder..We have an issue, some times multiple user may work in same file at the same time..So when both user do some changes in the file..Only the data saved by user who closed finally will be saved..

- To solve this issue whats the best solution ?
- I am using **Tortoise SVN**..Does it have any feature to solve this ?  Then i can easily implement...
- Can i execute any script that check whether the file is currently used by any other user and inform the user.. In windows, is it easy to do ?
- Or if there are any particular tool is there please specify..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Forget about that remote desktop ridiculousness, and set up proper SVN server on that machine instead. Otherwise it will only be pain, tears and data loss.

If you really have to, you can use a local repository.

```
svnadmin create C:\repo
```

Then each developer does:

```
svn co file:///C:/repo <developer's working copy>
```

Comment: Sorry dude, we have to go with remote desktop..we have to execute the file using a software in remote desktop..we cannot install that software in each developers system..

Comment: thank you friend..i thought of this solution but the problem is... we are keeping a standard folder structure each project contains a lot of files..if every developer keeps this much of files in the system..then the storage space will be an issue no ????????